# Change $invalid or required dxtagbox angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, devexpress, required, devextreme

I am trying to validate a form using $invalid, I don´t even need a controller for that, this Works great with input and checkboxes, but when I use devextreme widgets it seems to fail.

This is my simple form

```
<form name="step1" role="form" novalidate>
    <div id="Chk1" class="checkBox" dx-check-box="Chk1_Options" name="Chk1" value="Values.Chk1" ng-model="Values.Chk1" ></div>
    <div dx-tag-box="tag_options" id="Tag_Options" name="Tag_Options" ng-model="Values.Tag_Options" ></div>
    <p class="help-block">
        <span ng-show="step1.Tag_Options.$invalid ">Select at list One Option</span>
    </p>
    .....
</form>
```

In my Controller

```
app.controller("Controller1", ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', 
function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, $window ) {

    ...

    $scope.Values = {};
    $scope.Tag_Options_disabled=true;

    $scope.Chk1_Options = {
        text: "Check if Need it",
        value: false,
        onValueChanged: function (info) {
            // When the new value is Checked
            if (info.value) {
                // Enable the TagBox using bindingOptions on Tag_Options
                $scope.Tag_Options_disabled=true;
                // Reset TagBox Contaier
                $scope.Tag_Options_instance.reset();
                // Also Clear Values
                $scope.Values.Tag_Options=null;
                // ********** I need to make it "required". ********** 
                document.getElementById("Tag_Options").required = true;
            } else {
                // ****** if I deselect CheckBox then I need to make it NOT required so the form can be Valid ****** 
                document.getElementById("Tag_Options").required = false;
                // Then Disable the TagBox using bindingOptions on Tag_Options
                $scope.Tag_Options_disabled=true;
                // Reset TagBox Contaier in case something was there
                $scope.Tag_Options_instance.reset();
                // Also Clear Values
                $scope.Values.Tag_Options=null;
            }

        }
    }


    $scope.Tag_Options = {
        datasource: data,
        valueExp: "Id",
        displayExpr: "Ítem_Name",
        showSelectionControls: true,
        bindingOptions: {
            disabled: 'Tag_Options_disabled'
        },
        onInitialized: function (e) {
            $scope.Tag_Options_instance = e.component;
        }

    }


}
```

I've tried with

- document.getElementById("xxx").setAttribute("required", true);
- tag_Options.attributes["aria-invalid"].value = true; <<-- I don't know why this element was created but it appears on attributes of the object

At the end it Works ONLY on the second time I check the Checkbox, but even when it Works I can't find the right attribute to initialize it and the make it work since the first time.

Can anyone help me, I've been working arroung for 3 days I am giving up.

Comment: Did you try to use built-in DevExtreme [validation](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/Guide/Widgets/Common/UI_Widgets/Validation_-_MVVM_Approach/)? Refer this [sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdbLbG), as well.